# orderColumn for sorting does not work on yajra datatable

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

I'm using [Yajra datatable](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) package on laravel version `8.0`.

before that I used older versions, I use `->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` to sort data based on an specific column.

But in newer version that is suggested use an `orderColumn` method to sort. But it does not work for me.

Suppose I want to sort all `Post`'s of my website as desc on field `created_at`. for that I wrote this :

```
$posts =
                Post::select(['post_id', 'post_title', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'picture', 'active', 'created_at', 'deleted_at']);

            if ($request->has('showDeleted') && $request->get('showDeleted') == 1) {
                $posts = $posts->withTrashed();
            }

            $datatable = app('datatables')->of($posts)
                ->orderColumn('created_at', '-created_at $1');

            return $datatable->make(true);
```

As you can see I used `orderColumn` but soring not work. and But I do not know how to use it properly.

Comment: There's no instance of `[order-column][2]` in your code, and what is `'-created_at $1'` supposed to do?

Comment: `[order-column][2]` was a typo in my question. `'-created_at $1'` is foe that I do not know how can use `orderColumn` method

Comment: We're you looking at this example? https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/order-column

Comment: I would think just using `->orderColumn("created_at")` would be fine; the second param seems to be a special use case.

Comment: @TimLewis, I got this error: `Missing argument 2 for Yajra\DataTables\QueryDataTable::orderColumn()`

Comment: Check the source for that: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/blob/8.0/src/QueryDataTable.php. This isn't the most well-documented feature, so I'm not 100% what it wants here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it late but this also need an answer.

[orderColumn function description here](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/8.0/order-column)

"In some cases, you may want to use a custom order sql for a specific column" mean that this function not use for normal case.
Normal case when you want to order by a field of the table, just click on that field column name, then the order will run auto, nothing to do more. Your case only normal order. No need to use orderColumn function.

In case you want to use orderColumn function. This is how to using it:

[Example using orderColumn](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/order-column)

This not run at the first load of datatable, you must click on table column name (updated_at) to make it do the Order query.

If you want to set default order by updated_at:

```
$html = $htmlBuilder
        ->parameters([
            'order' => [5, 'asc'] // here is the updated_at column number
        ])
        ->addColumn([
            'data' => 'id',
            'name' => 'id',
            'title' => 'id',
        ])
        ->addColumn([
            'data' => 'start_date',
            'name' => 'start_date',
            'title' => 'start_date',
        ])
        ->addColumn([
            'data' => 'end_date',
            'name' => 'end_date',
            'title' => 'end_date',
        ])
        ->addColumn([
            'data' => 'picture',
            'name' => 'picture',
            'title' => 'picture',
        ])
        ->addColumn([
            'data' => 'active',
            'name' => 'active',
            'title' => 'active',
        ])
        ->addColumn([
            'data' => 'created_at',
            'name' => 'created_at',
            'title' => 'created_at,
        ])
        ->addColumn([
            'data' => 'deleted_at',
            'name' => 'deleted_at',
            'title' => 'deleted_at',
        ]);
return view('path.to.view', compact('html'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
->orderBy('tableName.columnName', 'DESC');
```

Comment: Please explain why.